# Failed to create application - ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp

Tags: redhawksdr

I am running Redhawk 1.10.2 on a CentOS 6.6 (2.6.32-504) machine. I am getting the following error.

Failed to create application: test_051_103150756 Unable to make connection DDC0 in waveform 'test_051_103150756_1'; error occurred near line:2995 in file:ApplicationFactory_impl.cpp;
IDL:CF/ApplicationFactory/CreateApplicationError:1.0

This waveform was running on a CentOS 6.5 (2.6.32-71) machine with Redhawk 1.10.0. The waveform only has a DataConverter in it.

Comment: There's only a DataConverter, but it looks like there is a connection in the waveform.  On your old installation was there a device that satisfied this connection that isn't running now?

Answer (score 0):

As pwolfram suggested, it looks as though you had a connection named DDC0.  Check your SAD.xml file to see how this connection is defined and it may shed light on the solution.  You can also increase the debug level of the domain and device manager to view how the waveform is being brought up and connections made.  If you are using the IDE to launch the domain & device manager, use the log level combo boxes to increase the log level.  If you are launching via the command line, use the -debug command line option.  In the IDE, these debug statements show up in the IDE's console view for the domain and device manager processes.